# COUNTIF cell description matches and within date range

Tags: excel, formula, countif

Hi I am after some help with a COUNTIF formula, I want to add 1 to cell 
if the 3 criteria are met (see image) =COUNTIF(K4:K20,D2 AND L4:L20,C6 AND M4:M20,B7) i can get the 2 count from =COUNTIF(K4:K20,D2) but the formula does not work with the AND L4:L20,C6 AND M4:M20,B7

[image]

Any help would be great

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58272057/edit) to show us some sample data and the expected result?

Comment: please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and don't forget to read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) and [I downvoted because no attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/). Also check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and more good information at ["help center".](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Question has been updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for first, I'd split your B column in two columns FROM and TO. This helps countifs to evaluate if time is after ( >= ) FROM and before (<) TO.

If you are asking what should you write in your C7 formula, this could be something like (according to columns in my screenshot):

```
=COUNTIFS(G:G,$C$5,H:H,">="&A6,H:H,"<"&B6,F:F,$B$2)
```

so use **">=" & cell** to evaluate if time if after FROM columns; and **"<" & cell** to evaluate if is before TO column.

I paste this screenshot of I'd solve this problem:

[screeshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHP3E.png)

and [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BSuZxpKbkzZ_lCEtxA1YjEz4qmaWhj5f/view?usp=sharing) you have a working example

Comment: Thank you worked great, Thanks for the tip on splitting the time in to 2 columns